# Switch between apps by both option+tab and Cmd+Tab

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have keyboard attached to my Mac. I would like to switch between apps with Cmd+Tab key on my laptop, and with option+Tab on my keyboard.

The easier way to do that is to enable both Cmd+Tab and Option+Tab. I tried to use third-party software (BetterTouchTool) with no luck.

What other options do I have?

Comment: what keyboard is it

Comment: @Buscar웃 it's "amazon basics" keyboard with 102 keys

Comment: do you have both keyboard showing in syst pref, is the external a BT type

Comment: @Buscar웃 how do I see those? I don't see any keyboards in system preferences